# How to iterate an array inside html file and view its element in Framework7 V1?

Tags: html-framework-7

How to display images **which base64 imageURLs** are containing in an array. Here I need to iterate **imageArray** and view images by getting array elements' value. In the following code, **{{imageArray}}** is representing the array.

```
<p><img src="{{imageArray}}" ></p>
```

Currently, I can view them by following way.

```
<p><img src="{{imageArray[0]}}" ></p>
<p><img src="{{imageArray[1]}}" ></p>
```

But I need to iterate it dynamiccaly according to the size of array.

Comment: FTR, the {{handle-bar synatx like this}} is specifically from Template7. Which is added as part of Framework7. Documentation for it can be found here http://idangero.us/template7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer after struggling for several hours. Each element of the array can be accessed using **this**  keyword. So I can iterate through the array and view images using following way.

```
{{#each imageArray}}
   <p><img src={{this}} class="payment-slip-image-view"></p>
{{/each}}
```